# Undefined variable: _SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

help me please, I have my principal page php with a $_SESSION.
page1.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$consulta = "select t.num_ticketfrom sdg_ticket t where t.cod_tipo_incidente=2 and t.cod_usuario='".$_SESSION['sdg_usuario']."' ";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function ()
    {
    $("#notificaciones").load("page2.php").fadeIn("slow"); }, 30000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <li id="notificaciones" class="dropdown">
                        <?php include("page2.php"); ?>
 </li>
</body>
</html>
```

second page
page2.php

```
<?php 
    include("conexion.php");
       $count="SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM sdg_ticket t,
      sdg_usuario u,
      sdg_estado_ticket e
    WHERE u.cod_empresa      = t.cod_empresa
    AND u.cod_usuario        = t.cod_usuario
    AND e.cod_empresa        = t.cod_empresa
    AND e.cod_estado_ticket  = t.cod_estado_ticket
    AND t.cod_estado_ticket <>7
    and t.cod_usuario   ='".$_SESSION['sdg_usuario']."'";
?>
```

setInterval() in the page1.php refresh every 30000 time, 
in the second load get this

"Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /srv/www/htdocs/lite/page2.php on line 12"

Comment: Does page2 have `session_start();`?

Comment: `page2.php` has only 4 lines, how are you getting error on line 12? show us the full code man.

Answer (score 3):

you are missing `session_start();` in the page 2

Comment: may be conexion.php contain `session_start()`

Comment: conexion.php not contain session_start()

Comment: @user2956927 did you add `session_start();` at the top in page2 ?

Answer (score 0):

page1 code is

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$consulta = "select t.num_ticketfrom sdg_ticket t where t.cod_tipo_incidente=2 and   t.cod_usuario='".$_SESSION['sdg_usuario']."' ";
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function ()
{
$("#notificaciones").load("page-2.php").fadeIn("slow"); }, 3000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<li id="notificaciones" class="dropdown">
                    <?php include("page-2.php"); ?>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

page2 code is

```
﻿<?php
session_start();  
include("conexion.php");
   $count="SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM sdg_ticket t
    WHERE u.cod_empresa      = t.cod_empresa
    and t.cod_usuario   ='".$_SESSION['sdg_usuario']."'";
```

?>